# Valor de variável no meio de um LINK em html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

A ideia é passar um número de telefone no link para chamada direta no WhatsApp:

```
 <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+55'NUMERO'&text=blablabla">
```

Botões e afins já estão feitos, só gostaria de saber como coloco a variável que **já tenho** onde está 'NUMERO' ali em cima.

Tentei da seguinte maneira

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+55NUMERO&text=blablabla" >
    <button (click)= "troca(var)"> 
    LINK
    </button>
</a>
```

e no .ts (projeto sendo feito com Angular) assim:

```
troca(n){
    const link = document.querySelector('a');
    link.href = link.href.replace('NUMERO', n);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há diversas formas uma delas é usar a função `replace`:

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a');

link.href = link.href.replace('NUMERO', '123451234');

console.log(link);
```

```html
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+55NUMERO&text=blablabla">
```

Se você está usando o Angular ai muda completamente, um exemplo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-example',
    template: `
        <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+55{{ numero }}&text=blablabla" >
            <button (click)= "troca('123451234')"> LINK</button>
        </a>
    `,
    styles: []
})
export class ExampleComponent {

    numero: string = '';

    constructor() { }

    troar(novoNumero): void {
        this.numero = novoNumero;
    }

}
```

Comment: Editei baseado no que me mandou, porém não consegui, sabe o que pode estar dando errado ainda?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Deu certo, valeu.